# Is there a faster way to load all mobile contacts w/ Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

Heyoo! first of all, I know there are other threads yet none of them helped me so I'm asking again.

My goal is to receive and show all mobile contacts **quickly** in Flutter, in average there are around 500 mobile contacts in any-given regularly used phone.
So far I've used `flutter_contacts` and `contacts_service` without any improvement.

until now I've tried:

- pulling contacts without requesting contacts' thumbnails:

```dart
contacts_ = await ContactsService.getContacts(withThumbnails: false);
```

and basically that's it.

to render the contacts:

```dart
ListView.builder(
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: contacts.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Column(children: [
      Card(
          child: ContactItem(
        contacts[index].name,
        contacts[index].phoneNumber,
        contacts[index].isSelected,
        index,
      ))
    ]);
  },
),
```

Thanks in advance for any help that will be given and may I solve this problem in a way that will be more user convenient <3.

Comment: `I know there are other threads yet none of them helped me so I'm asking again.` if that's the case it's always better to show what you've tried and what hasn't worked, otherwise you might just get the same answers for stuff you've already tried, which is just a waste of time for everyone

Comment: @a_local_nobody Sorry forgot about that part lol, although I tried only one thing that the threads recommended I added it.

Comment: I am still not clear what you are trying to achieve? Is the package not pulling 500 contacts ? is the package not fast enough?

Comment: @Md.KamrulAmin The package isn't fast enough, It takes more than 4/5 minutes to pull 300 contacts in a new phone.